# How to pass parameters to Fragment when it resume?

Tags: android

I have a TextViewerFragment to display text files content. It has a `newInstance` method:

```
public static TextViewerFragment newInstance() {
    return new TextViewerFragment();
}
```

and use `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_menu, tvFragment).commit();` to display it.

At the same time I need to pass `tvFragment` a file path to tell it which file to display. I know how to pass parameters via `Bundle` when `new` it. But what about reuse this tvFragment?  How to pass parameters when I `replace` an old `tvFragment` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

As the documentation for getArguments() suggests it returns a Bundle of the arguments passed at creation, as such this can not be changed after the fragment has been activated.

If you want to reuse the fragment then simply expose a method to set the path in a variable. You don't have to insist on using arguments, just create your own custom class that extends fragment.

As a side note. This newinstance method doesn't make any sense, since you simply create a new fragment every time.

You can declare

```
private TextViewerFragment mInstance;

public TextViewerFragment getInstance(){
   if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new TextViewerFragment();
   }
return mInstance;
}
```

And then you create a public method to set the path.